# Setup subviews before or after async data fetch?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Suppose I have an iOS app, and a view

**HeaderView.h**

```
@interface HeaderView : UIView
@end
```

And the implementation file

**HeaderView.m**

```
@interface HeaderView ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIButton *leftButton;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UILabel *centeredLabel;

@propert (strong, nonatomic) NSString *someStringFromTheServer; // Gets fetched first thing from server in async operation. 

@end

@implementation HeaderView
- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
       [self runAsyncOperationToFetchDataFromServerAndThenSetupSubViews]
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)runAsyncOperationToFetchDataFromServerAndThenSetupSubViews {
   /// async call to server that sets someStringFromTheServer field.


   // now call the callback after async server fetch is done
   [self callBackToSetupSubViewsNow];
}

- (void)callBackToSetupSubViewsNow {
  centeredLabel = ... //alloc and initialize
  [centeredLabel setText:someStringFromTheServer]; // setText:someStringFromTheServer will be correct and filled from server.

  // add label into the main view "self"
  [self addSubView:centeredLabel]; 
}
@end
```

I am new to iOS and I am wondering if this is correct? The main issue is that, I am doing the server call first and THEN setting up the subviews.

Is that correct or should the order be

1) Set up subivews, alloc all the label, button, but set all as HIDDEN
2) runServer call and then modify the already added subviews from (1), change text etc
3) Unhide the subviews (label, button, etc)

What is the correct approach?

- Server call then initialize/fill/setup subviews

OR

- initialize/hide subviews then server call then fill/set subviews and unhide

Comment: Try to runServer from viewWillAppear, this will guarantee that views are really created and available to populate your fetched data

Comment: Seems like an odd approach. What if the Async call fails? Or gets delayed (bad connection, etc)? What if the UI elements in your view also affect the size of the view? In general, I would say: setup your view in init - likely with a spinner / activity indicator to let the user know it's working - and then have your controller tell the view to "do its Async" operation. When the Async call finishes, update the UI